# How to handle a scenario when Payment is successfull but user pressed back button

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, payment-gateway, razorpay

I am using `RazoprPay` in `.NET MVC` application. I know I dont have any code to show here but a question.

For example, from application we requested a payment and user entered all valid data to proceed for the payment. Now as soon as the payment is successful, user hits on the address bar, or click on the back button or his internet got disconnected.

In this case, if we are store payment information in our database on payment's post method, we could not able to get the information as payment happened but its associated post method didn't executed.

How to deal with this scenario?

Comment: Well, throw away all stored information the moment the payment is successful. Also you could calculate a hash from articles/user/what ever and send it with your payment request. If that hash is sent more then once, ignore it.

Comment: research the PRG pattern

Comment: Thank you for the hint. But it's not actually a problem of doubly post. It's something when the payment gateway accepted the payment but application connection got disconnected to store that information.